# git mass removal

Tags: git

Let's say I have *a lot* of files in my remote origin of a repository that were *deleted* locally, but never removed from version control. Is there a way to simply remove all the remote files with a command or script? If I was in the repository folder, could I do:

```
git sync
```

And it would say "this file doesn't exist locally, so remove it from the origin".

I'd be ok with a comparison script that checks local vs. remote, I just can't seem to find anything, and I know this must have been done already.

Comment: How about `git rm all_the_files_not_needed_anymore`?

Comment: Its not that simple. They are in in sub directories, etc. LOTS OF THEM. There has to be some sort of sync function.

Comment: `git commit -a`? What does `git status` tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps
[`git push`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html)

```sh
git rm foo.txt
git commit
git push -f
```

Answer (score 0):

Locally, make sure you remove the files from the repo:

```
 git add -A .
 git commit -am 'deletions'
 git push
```

Now on the remote

```
 git pull
 git clean -dfn .
```

If the list of deletions is ok with you, **drop the `-n` to actually delete**